# Algorithm to identify differences between two sorted data sets

Tags: sorting, efficiency, logic, pseudocode, difference

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**: Print the items that differ between the following two left and right sorted data sets:

```
A       A
B       C
C       D
D       E
G       F
H       EOF
EOF
```

The proposed solution should print:

```
B E F G H
```

Here is my data-driven implementation of this algorithm in pseudo-code. It appears to produce the desired results so my questions are:

- Are there any flaws in terms of logic, efficiency or anything else using this approach?
- Would this approach be called a data-driven design or would it be categorized under a different name?

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
METHOD PRINT_DIFFERENCES
    LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()
    RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()

    WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF
        WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND LEFT_KEY IS LESS THAN RIGHT_KEY
            PRINT LEFT_KEY
            LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()
        LOOP

        WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_KEY IS LESS THAN LEFT_KEY
            PRINT RIGHT_KEY
            RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()
        LOOP

        WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND LEFT_KEY IS EQUAL TO RIGHT_KEY
            LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()
            RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()
        LOOP
    LOOP

    WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF
        PRINT LEFT_KEY
        LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()
    LOOP

    WHILE RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF
        PRINT RIGHT_KEY
        RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()
    LOOP
METHOD END

METHOD READ_LEFT_RECORD
    RESULT = MOVE TO NEXT LEFT RECORD

    IF RESULT IS EQUAL TO TRUE THEN
        SET LEFT_KEY FROM CURRENT LEFT CURSOR    
    END IF

    RETURN RESULT
METHOD END

METHOD READ_RIGHT_RECORD
    RESULT = MOVE TO NEXT RIGHT RECORD

    IF RESULT IS EQUAL TO TRUE THEN
        SET RIGHT_KEY FROM CURRENT RIGHT CURSOR    
    END IF

    RETURN RESULT
METHOD END
```

Comment: that "pseudo code" really hurt the eyes

Comment: A pseudo code is supposed to be easier to read than actual code .. right ?

Answer (score 3):

I would simplify

```
WHILE LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF AND RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF
    IF LEFT_KEY IS LESS THAN RIGHT_KEY
        PRINT LEFT_KEY
        LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()

    ELSE IF RIGHT_KEY IS LESS THAN LEFT_KEY
        PRINT RIGHT_KEY
        RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()

    ELSE 
        LEFT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_LEFT_RECORD()
        RIGHT_DATA_NOT_EOF = CALL READ_RIGHT_RECORD()
LOOP
```

Comment: your while loop is AND'ed ... would'nt this fail for mismatches at the tail end?